# Should Qt class data members of a C++ class be initialized before being used?

Tags: c++, qt, class, member-initialization

There are many C++ programming best practices that are proposed in many articles and books. Following is a subset that is related to C++ class data members:

1. Make sure that objects are initialized before they are used.
2. Make sure that all constructors initialize everything in the object.
3. It is usually more effective to initialize data members in the initializer list of each constructor than in its body.
4. In the initializer list, data members should be listed in the order they are declared.

Consider the following class with data members of Qt class types:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
private:
    int myInt;
    QString myQString;
    QList<QString> myQList;
    QHash<int, QString> myQHash;
    char * pChar;
};
```

By applying the above best practices, the constructor code would look like the following:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    myInt(0),    // OK, primitive should be initialized.
    myQString(),    // Is this really needed?
    myQList(),     // Is this really needed?
    myQHash(),    // Is this really needed?
    pChar(NULL)    // OK, pointer should be initialized.
{
}
```

However, I have the impression that not all of the Qt class data members need to be initialized. But I am not 100 % sure of this. Some developers argue that by putting all the data members in the initialization list, we may avoid omitting the initialization of some important data members that should be initialized. However, if this is a real concern, I would prefer putting a comment line for each data member that does not need to be initialized, for example:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    myInt(0), 
    //myQString(),
    //myQList(),
    //myQHash(),
    pChar(NULL) 
{
}
```

To summarize, I would like to know when a Qt class data member should be initialized, and when the initialization is not needed, and why. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that, for all the Qt classes involved in class `MyClass`, we can assume that they have a 0-argument constructor available. That is, `QString::QString()`, `QList::QList()` and `QHash::QHash()` are available. With this assumption, the original question can lead to 2 additional questions:
Q1: Are the 2 versions of `MyClass::MyClass()` above equivalent? That is, do they produce 2 objects of same content?
Q2: Is one version faster than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have a default constructor of a class then you must initialize it in initializer list, and it is not required to call default constructor in initializer list. It is not Qt specific it is a general rule for any class. When you have a default constructor(which takes 0 argument) even if you don't call it in initializer list, it will be called automatically.

**Update:**

> Q1: Are the 2 versions of MyClass::MyClass() above equivalent? That
>   is, do they produce 2 objects of same content?

Yes.

> Q2: Is one version faster than the other?

You can type the second version faster ;-), there is no performance difference.

Comment: My understanding of your answer is: If `myQString(),` line is not explicitly placed on the initializer list, the compiler will implicitly call the 0-argument constructor of `QString`. So the 2 versions of `MyClass::MyClass()` above will produce 2 objects of same content, and with a similar time effort. So either version is good, but the 1st version may be preferable. Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: I would prefer DRY(don't repeat yourself)  If compiler is doing the same thing on your behalf then why do you want to write it yourself, I would prefer second version because you can get warnings of the order, and to resolve warnings you will take time to see the order of data members in header file.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. Since the 2 versions are equivalent, I would prefer the 1st version. I don't mind writing some additional lines of code as long as the code is easier to understand and maintain by other developers - This is my personal preference though. If I were the only developer of the class, I would also choose the 2nd version as you did J

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor of QObject's will be called regardless you call it explicitly, or it's called implicitly when your object is created.

You may put a debug message into QObject constructor code and see for yourself, it's Open Source for truth's sake! :)